# How can you tell what a RoR site is being hosted with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-ec2, engineyard

I want to know if someone's site is using Heroku, Engine Yard, self-hosted on EC2, or something different.  They use Ruby on Rails.  Is there a good way to figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

Your only clue will be looking at where the DNS record is pointing at, eg `nslookup www.kyan.com` will show you that it's a CNAME to a herokuapp.com domain. Heroku and EY all use EC2 so the IP address range will show you it's an Amazon IP address. Perhaps if you reveal the domain we can all have a poke.